# apt-get commands doesn't work in docker containers

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to install some packages in a docker image, but apt-get commands seems not to work...

When I try this in a container based on ubuntu:16.04

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
```

I got this:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openssh-server
```

I tried to do this in a Dockerfile like this

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install openssh-server
CMD bin/bash
```

and build this with

```
sudo docker build -t imagetest .
```

but I got this:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 00fd29ccc6f1
Step 2/3 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-server
 ---> Running in ee011c1239d0
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package openssh-server
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-server' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I searched on the official doc and some forums but none of the answers I found help me and are old...

Some of them said to restart the docker service, but it doesn't work for me..
Some others said to use `apt-get update -qq`, but it doesn't work too...

So I came here to ask directly and have a recent answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running behind a firewall proxy?

Comment: No, but I'm on a VM with NAT configuration

Comment: Try switching to bridge option and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: I can't switch to bridge option because my network requires ssh key authentication that my VM does not have ... 
You think it can be because of this ? but I can use apt-get commands on my VM, it doesn't work specificly in Docker files or containers..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If apt-get is working fine on the VM, you can build the container using network host mode.

```
docker build --network=host ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the same issue (maybe not the same root cause) by using the same proxy settings as in apt.conf for my docker.

Just make a copy of atp.conf:

```
cp /etc/apt/apt.conf apt.conf
```

and then add the following to the docker-file before doing any apt-calls:

```
COPY apt.conf /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

I hope it can help someone.